# Simple Interference of laser beams

Tags: interference

How this laser beams interfere each other if they doesn't meet in some point of space?

[image: a]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hyportnex's answer is a good one, but if you want to stick to (to some extent) ray optics, look at it this way.

Assume the reflection at point a is at angle $\theta_1$ but the reflection at point C is at angle $\theta_1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a very small number. 
Then the two rays will converge at some point at a distance related to $1/\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is small, this convergence point is far away.

Now consider the limit as $\epsilon$ tends toward 0. The diagram becomes the one you presented, and the point of convergence moves to infinity.

Nonetheless, the result of the analysis will be useful even when we actually observe the reflection at a finite distance, so long as that distance is large enough.

It's a pretty common theme in physics that we analyze something "at an infinite distance" or "with a small deviation from steady state" or whatever. All of these analyses really mean taking the limit as some parameter of the problem goes to 0 or infinity, and then testing experimentally that these approximations are close enough in some real-world scenario.

Comment: I can't get your idea. If waves are parallel they do not converge at any point...

Comment: I'm saying consider the case where they are not parallel, but converging at some faraway point. Now consider moving the point where they converge away toward infinity.

Comment: Yes, but beams are strictly parallel..

Comment: @santimirandarp, they don't have to be. You could make them have any angles you want. At some particular angles, they're going to produce constructive interference. That's what you're trying to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Light rays do not interfere, light waves do. The drawing shows rays that are orthogonal to the propagating phase fronts, and those are not constrained in space as rays do. Phase fronts are "large" compared to the scales your drawing shows, hence they do interfere.

Comment: I didn't understand. Link or images?

Comment: How do I know the length of a front?

Comment: @santimirandarp In principle, they are infinite planes, or they are limited by the diaphragm (iris) of the generating light source. The latter being of finite size the phase fronts far away from the source appear to be spherical waves whose minimum observable "flat" portion is at least a few wavelengths across.

Answer (score -1):

Light classically is described with electric and magnetic fields building up the propagation of light, and [these fields have an extent in space time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Derivation_from_electromagnetic_theory) and two beams ( as the two reflected ones) can mathematically show interference, depending on the boundary conditions.

[image: light]

Lasing is a quantum mechanical phenomenon . In general, for interferences the underlying level of photons, elementary particles which in zillions build up light, help to clarify the classical light interference

The photon framework is not necessary to understand the interference above  which  is  consistent with the classical one.

Lazing though is very interesting, and interference effects can appear that demand knowledge of the whole setup, detecting surfaces and generating pulses. This [mit video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU) is instructive: