# How a reflection grating works?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

Diffraction grating:

**What is**

> component of optical devices consisting of a surface ruled with close,
>   equidistant, and parallel lines for the purpose of resolving light
>   into spectra.
>   (...) Only those waves of a given wavelength will be conserved, all the rest being destroyed because of interference with one another.

Taken from [britannica encycl](https://www.britannica.com/technology/diffraction-grating#ref272537)

**Problem**

I am having troubles with this kind of image:

[image]

**Question**

Is the reflection angle different to each wavelenght? why it is so?

I think I can't get the idea about how it works.

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328250/104696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to the thin film problem in your previous [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/371079/simple-interference-of-laser-beams). You can consider how the light will behave when reflecting at any angle you like. At certain angles there will be constructive interference and at other angles destructive interference.

Which angles produce constructive interference will depend on the wavelength, because constructive interference happens when $\Delta S = n\lambda$.